# Не запускается один тест из списка при вызове всего пакета в Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium, test-automation, testng

В пакете `tests` шесть тестов. По отдельности они все успешно запускаются. Если запустить весь пакет `tests`, то `GroupCreationTests` почему-то пропускается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код `GroupCreationTests` и `GroupDeletionTests` на мой взгляд аналогичны.

```
package ru.stqa.pft.addressbook.tests;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import ru.stqa.pft.addressbook.model.GroupData;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class GroupCreationTests extends TestBase{

  @Test
  public void testGroupCreation() throws Exception {
    app.getNavigationHelper().gotoGroupPage();
    List<GroupData> before = app.getGroupHelper().getGroupList();
    GroupData group = new GroupData("test2", null, null);
    app.getGroupHelper().createGroup(group);
    List<GroupData> after = app.getGroupHelper().getGroupList();
    Assert.assertEquals(after.size(), before.size() + 1);

    group.setId(after.stream().max((o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId())).get().getId());
    before.add(group);
    Comparator<? super GroupData> byId = (g1, g2) -> Integer.compare(g1.getId(), g2.getId());
    before.sort(byId);
    after.sort(byId);
    Assert.assertEquals(before, after);
  }

}
```

```
package ru.stqa.pft.addressbook.tests;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import ru.stqa.pft.addressbook.model.GroupData;

import java.util.List;

public class GroupDeletionTests extends TestBase{

  @Test
  public void testGroupDeletion() throws Exception {
    app.getNavigationHelper().gotoGroupPage();
    if (! app.getGroupHelper().isThereAGroup()) {
        app.getGroupHelper().createGroup(new GroupData("test1", "test1", "test1"));
    }
    List<GroupData> before = app.getGroupHelper().getGroupList();
    app.getGroupHelper().selectGroup(before.size() - 1);
    app.getGroupHelper().deleteSelectedGroups();
    app.getGroupHelper().returnToGroupPage();
    List<GroupData> after = app.getGroupHelper().getGroupList();
    Assert.assertEquals(after.size(), before.size() - 1);

    before.remove(before.size() - 1);
    Assert.assertEquals(before, after);
  }


}
```